# On which functions spaces $T:f(x,y)\mapsto f(x,x)$ is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a Banach spaces of functions on $\mathbb R^2.$ Define operator 
$$Tf(x,y)= f(x,x)$$ for $x,y \in \mathbb R, f\in X.$

**Questions**: 
(1) Dose there exists examples (or known theorems) of functions spaces $X$ and $Y$ so that operator $T$ maps $X$ to $Y$  with $\|Tf\|_{Y} \leq C \|f\|_{X}$ for some constant $C>0.$

(2) Specifically, I'm curious to see Banach spaces  like, Sobolev spaces $H^s(\mathbb R^2) (s\in\mathbb R)$, and Fourier-Lebesgue spaces $\mathcal{F}L^p(\mathbb R^2) (1\leq p \leq \infty).$

Any references and comments would be helpful to me.

**Edit**: Using the comment below first we recall following.
We first define trace operator: $T_rf(x,y)=f(x,0)$ $(x,y \in \mathbb R).$ Trace Theorem: Let$s>\frac{1}{2}$. Then $T_r:H^{s}(\mathbb R^2) \to H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb R)$ with the norm inequality $$\|T_rf(x,y)\|_{H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb R)} \leq C \|f(x,y)\|_{H^{s}(\mathbb R^2)}$$

From this, Can  we derive
 $$\|f(x,x)\|_{H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb R)} \leq C \|f\|_{H^{s}(\mathbb R^2)}?$$

Or I'm not sure flowing  make sense or we can expect:
$$\|f(x,x)\|_{H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb R^2)} \leq C \|f\|_{H^{s}(\mathbb R^2)}?$$

Comment: For (1) with with $X=L^\infty(\Bbb R^2)$ and $Y=L^\infty(\Bbb R)$ such an inequality is true.
For (2) as you need at least enough regularity to ensure that the trace of $f$ on the line $y=x$ (of codimension $1$) exist. For example for sobolev spaces you need $s>1/2$, then by trace theorem $Y=H^{s-1/2}$.

Comment: @Delta-u: Thanks. Can you give me specific reference for your second comment ($H^s$)? I'm curious to learn the proof. (I'm also wondering, Is this problem related to trace operator or so )

Comment: What is trace theorem and how to apply here? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what is the best reference in English, but any reference treating of $H^s$ should be ok I think (for example [one of the first result on google](http://www.ltcc.ac.uk/media/london-taught-course-centre/documents/Applied-Computational-Methods---Notes-4.pdf)).

Comment: A trace theorem is just a theorem stating that a trace operator from one particular space to an other is well defined (and continuous) so it is indeed related to trace operator :-).

Comment: @Delta-u: Thanks. But still I'm wondering to derive  $\|f(x,x)\| \leq C \|f(x,y)\|$ inequality using trace theorem. I have edited question, please have look. Trace theorem deals with $f(x,y)\mapsto f(x,0)$, on the other hand we have here $f(x,y)\mapsto f(x,x)$. Please can  clarify bit more?

Comment: If we take the linear change of variables $u=x+y,v=x-y$ then as it is linear $f(x,y)$ and $g(u,v)=f((u+v)/2,(u-v)/2)$ have (up to a constant) the same norms.
But $f(x,x)=g(x,0)$. (The idea is to use a lienar transformation to transform $\{(x,y), y=x\}$ into$\{(u,v), u=0\}$

Comment: @Delta-u, How can you prove the theorem for $X = L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $Y = L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$? The diagonal $\{(x,x)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is of measure zero. I can see easily that $\|Tf\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty$ for simple tensors (finite sums of functions of the form $f_1(x)f_2(y)$), but $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not the norm closure of simple tensors, so you can not extend the map. In weaker topologies, like the $\sigma(L^1(\mathbb{R}^2))$, you have that simple tensors are dense but I think $T$ is not $\sigma(L^1(\mathbb{R}^2))$-continuous.

Comment: You are absolutely correct it was a mistake, sorry... It is $C^0$ and not $L^\infty$.